# JQuery mobile not working with rails devise

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using rails 5 with `gem 'jquery_mobile_rails', '1.4.5'` and `gem 'jquery-turbolinks'` which seem to work when I remove the `turbolinks` gem.

my set up is as follows in application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery.mobile
//= require_tree .
```

The problem is that when I use devise authentication my app doesn't load the navbars at the first log in instance and only shows when I refresh. I have found that if I remove the authentication bellow `<% if user_signed_in? %>` then the issue goes away but I need authentication?

_nav.html.erb:

```
 <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>
            <%= link_to 'corners', corners_path %>
            <% else %>
                <%= link_to('Login', new_user_session_path) %></br>
                Don't have an account? <%= link_to('Sign Up',new_user_registration_path) %>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Likewise the same thing happens when I log out the page is blank but I have to reload it in order for it to work.
I have read some issues but can't see, to find the answer for this

Comment: Have you refresh the ` <div data-role="navbar">`

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by "refresh" the div? can you elaborate please?